# How can you make a limit to a border?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to generate a grid of 10x10 with a randomly generated black box, currently my game looks like this:

[image: I generate 5 black boxes randomly in a row]

The 5 black boxes are generated randomly in a row, but it goes outside of the border and it generates a black box down which breaks the row. I want to set limits to the border so that it can't be crossed. Meaning that all of the generated boxes will be in one row.

This is the code i've implemented:

```
import React, {useEffect  ,useState} from 'react'
import Ship from '../components/ShipGenerate.js'
import '../style/style.css'

function Grid(props) {

  const [active, setActive] = useState(true)
  const [changedItems, setChangedItems] = useState([])

  let grid = [];
  let aiGrid = []
  let randomNumberArray = [...Array(1)].map(e=>Math.random()*110|0)

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    let result = randomNumberArray.map(function(val){return ++val;})
      let finalResult = randomNumberArray.push(result[i])
  }
console.log(randomNumberArray)

  for (var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
     if (randomNumberArray.includes(i)) {    // ---> checking with this condition if the index in the random array to give it a different className
        grid.push(<div className="hello"></div>)
     } else {
        grid.push(<div className="boxGrid"></div>)
     }
  }

  const onClick = (e) => e.target.textContent = "x"

    return (
        <div>
  <div onClick={onClick} className="box">
    {grid}
  </div>


        </div>
    )
}

export default Grid
```

Comment: `[...Array(1)].map(e=>Math.random()*110|0)` generates an array containing one random integer value in the range [0, 110). That's 110 different possible values. But only 60 values with [0, 5] + 10 * [0, 9] are valid. You could either map the range [0, 59] into the set of valid values or you could generate two random values and calculate the final value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[...Array(1)].map(e=>Math.random()*110|0)` generates an array containing one random integer value in the range [0, 110). That's 110 different possible values. But only 60 values with [0, 6] + 11 * [0, 9] are valid. You could either map the range [0, 59] into the set of valid values or you could generate two random values and calculate the final value.

Use

```
let randomNumberArray = [...Array(1)].map(() => (Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
```

instead of

```
let randomNumberArray = [...Array(1)].map(e=>Math.random()*110|0)
```

Here is an example:

```js
let randomNumberArray = [...Array(1)].map(() => (Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let result = randomNumberArray.map(function(val) {
    return ++val;
  })
  let finalResult = randomNumberArray.push(result[i])
}

const grid = document.querySelector('#grid');
for (var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
  if (randomNumberArray.includes(i)) {
    grid.innerHTML += '<div class="hello"></div>';
  } else {
    grid.innerHTML += '<div class="boxGrid"></div>';
  }
}
```

```css
.hello,
.boxGrid {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.boxGrid {
  background: aqua;
}

#grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 572px;
  width: 520px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: this makes the black boxes disappear

Comment: I will try to build a reproducible example in react

Comment: @Chen I added an example